efficient conversion of non-repeating sequences to long format
I have a matrix
set.seed(1)
m <- matrix(sample(-1:1,30,replace = T,prob = c(1,5,1)),
             ncol = 3, dimnames = list(NULL, LETTERS[1:3]))

...
m
       A  B  C
 [1,]  0  0 -1
 [2,]  0  0  0
 [3,]  0  0  0
 [4,] -1  0  0
 [5,]  0  1  0
 [6,] -1  0  0
 [7,] -1  1  0
 [8,]  0 -1  0
 [9,]  0  0 -1
[10,]  0  1  0

I need to find non-repeating sequences (non-repeating sequences is what the rle algorithm does)

and convert them to long format like this:
   id name val
1   3    A   0
2   4    A  -1
3   5    A   0
4   7    A  -1
5  10    A   0
6   4    B   0
7   5    B   1
8   6    B   0
9   7    B   1
10  8    B  -1
11  9    B   0
12 10    B   1
13  1    C  -1
14  8    C   0
15  9    C  -1
16 10    C   0

I wrote some code that does this, but it is very slow for me. My code runs on small data ~2000 rows and 5 columns, but it runs many hundreds of thousands of times.
I'm looking for the most effective solution
here is my code:
rid <- apply(m, 2, \(colum) cumsum(rle(colum)$length))

long_df <- NULL
for(Name in names(rid)){
df <- cbind.data.frame(id   = rid[[Name]],
                       name = Name, 
                       val  = m[rid[[Name]],Name]) 

long_df <- rbind.data.frame(long_df, df)
}

long_df


Unit: milliseconds
             expr     min      lq      mean   median      uq     max neval
         my_fu(m)  3.3196  3.6157  4.293507  3.75735  4.0036 12.2766    30
    MrFlick_fu(m) 25.6869 26.5682 31.062887 27.22125 34.3767 60.2749    30
        one_fu(m)  3.0693  3.3389  3.507363  3.51300  3.6304  4.1176    30
   jblood94_fu(m)  1.3574  1.4510  1.621113  1.50865  1.5659  3.7355    30
 jblood94_2_fu(m)  1.0156  1.0660  1.197143  1.12360  1.2961  1.7586    30


Second attempt:
f0 <- function(m) {
  # OP approach
  rid <- apply(m, 2, \(colum) cumsum(rle(colum)$length))
  
  long_df <- NULL
  for(Name in names(rid)){
    df <- cbind.data.frame(id   = rid[[Name]],
                           name = Name, 
                           val  = m[rid[[Name]],Name]) 
    
    long_df <- rbind.data.frame(long_df, df)
  }
  
  long_df
}

f1 <- function(m) {
  # proposed approach 1
  r <- apply(m, 2, rle)
  data.frame(
    id = unlist(lapply(r, \(x) cumsum(x[[1]])), TRUE, FALSE),
    name = rep.int(colnames(m), sapply(r, \(x) length(x[[1]]))),
    val = unlist(lapply(r, "[[", 2), TRUE, FALSE)
  )
}

f2 <- function(m) {
  # proposed approach 2
  bln <- rbind(m[-1,] != m[-nrow(m),], TRUE)
  data.frame(
    id = which(bln, TRUE)[,1],
    name = rep.int(colnames(m), colSums(bln)),
    val = m[bln]
  )
}

Timing on a larger dataset.
m <- matrix(sample(-1:1, 1e4, 1, c(1, 5, 1)), 2e3, 5, 0, list(NULL, LETTERS[1:5]))

microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  f0 = f0(m),
  f1 = f1(m),
  f2 = f2(m),
  check = "equal"
)
#> Unit: microseconds
#>  expr      min        lq     mean    median        uq      max neval
#>    f0 1594.902 1716.3010 1926.045 1781.1510 2004.7515 7434.502   100
#>    f1  513.901  584.8005  826.936  645.8010  730.5005 6221.501   100
#>    f2  424.502  449.8510  660.544  490.2005  557.8015 6309.701   100


We can use dplyr and tidyr to help with this. First, rather than rle, we can write a helper function to find values that change.
non_repeat <- function(x) {
  x!=dplyr::lead(x, 1, dplyr::last(x)+1)
}

and then apply that to the data with
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

as.data.frame(m) %>% 
  mutate(id=row_number()) %>% 
  pivot_longer(-id) %>% 
  filter(non_repeat(value), .by=name) %>% 
  arrange(name, id)

which returns
      id name  value
   <int> <chr> <int>
 1     3 A         0
 2     4 A        -1
 3     5 A         0
 4     7 A        -1
 5    10 A         0
 6     4 B         0
 7     5 B         1
 8     6 B         0
 9     7 B         1
10     8 B        -1
11     9 B         0
12    10 B         1
13     1 C        -1
14     8 C         0
15     9 C        -1
16    10 C         0


Thanks, but your function is 7 times slower than mine, and I need a function at least 100 times faster than mine

I very much doubt that a 100x speedup is possible. Efficient Rcpp may be able to get a 10x speedup. If it is being run on hundreds of thousands of matrices, processing the matrices in parallel is an obvious approach.

Here is roughly 4.4 times faster than the for loop solution:
rle_long <- function(colname,mat){
  x <- rle(mat[,colname])
  id <- cumsum(x$lengths)
  df <- data.frame(id=id,name=colname,val=x$values)
}


do.call("rbind",lapply(colnames(m),rle_long,m))

   id name val
1   3    A   0
2   4    A  -1
3   5    A   0
4   7    A  -1
5  10    A   0
6   4    B   0
7   5    B   1
8   6    B   0
9   7    B   1
10  8    B  -1
11  9    B   0
12 10    B   1
13  1    C  -1
14  8    C   0
15  9    C  -1
16 10    C   0


Thanks, but your function is the same in efficiency as mine
